# Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32 Error on iOS WKWebView & Uno 2.4

Tags: c#, uwp, wkwebview, uno-platform, winui

I have an Uno WebAssembly app at [here](https://acmsearch.azurewebsites.net/), you can try it now.
Button click events not fire and doing nothing sometimes both on iOS and iPadOS WKWebview. They rarely work without problems. Sometimes cleaning web cache from Settings / Safari / Advanced Settings is solves problem. Unfortunately, this error is coming up again soon.

[image]

I have not any issue on desktop browser, the app running smoothly. I have iPhone X, iPad and iPhone 6. . The app works rarely without problems on X. Seems not run on others. The WebAssembly log on iOS is [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/files/4719089/click.log).

Is it depends on device RAM size on Apple Device ? The app runs just perfectly on Android WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update to Uno 2.4.4 or later, which contains a fix for pointers management for Safari on iOS.

Safari for iOS can return pointers being negative, which was causing trouble to the pointer management system in Uno. See [this Pull Request](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/3245) for more information.

Comment: I'm encountered a issue like it on iPhone 6. Fix in Uno.UI 2.4.4 and later is seems working on iPhone X, iPad Pro 2016 vs. which are have at least 2 GB Ram. Is iPhone 6's 1 GB RAM causes it ? https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23173536/83761089-83782280-a67e-11ea-9cdc-aa680d506bd9.gif